# cout print hex instead of decimal

Tags: c++

has it occurred to anyone that a simple `std::cout` might print a value in hex format when it is supposed to format just a decimal(like an integer)?

for example, I have a line as :

> std::cout << "_Agent [" << target << "] is still
>   among " << **((target->currWorker)->getEntities().size())** << " entities
>   of worker[" << target->currWorker << "]" << std::endl;

which would print :

> _Agent [0x2c6d530] is still among **0x1** entities of worker[0x2c520f0]

Note:

1-the said out put is sometime decimal and some times hex

2- the behaviour is smae even if I change `((target->currWorker)->getEntities().size())` to `(int)((target->currWorker)->getEntities().size())`

any hints?

thanks

Comment: Did you use `std::cout << std::hex ...` anywhere in your "real" code?

Comment: what is `target`? It seems that this is the address of `target`. All the hex's seem like address.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably have set std::cout to print hex in prior in the context of your code but forget to reset. For example:

```
std::cout<<std::hex<<12;
/*blah blah blah*/
std::cout<<12; //this will print in hex form still
```

so you have to do like the following

```
std::cout<<std::dec<<12;
```

to print in decimal form.

Answer (score 4):

Try to find line like this `std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex;` some where in your code, which sets `std::cout` to print output in hexadecimal with `0x` base indicator prefix.
To reset it to show decimal add this line `std::cout<<std::dec` before the current cout.

You can learn more about c++ io manipulators flags [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/)