# C++ -- Hex to String Conversion

Tags: c++, number-formatting

I'm trying to convert hex to string in C++. Is there any STL function for this?

For example,

```
int myHex = 0xff00;
string result = someFunc(myHex);

The result should be "0xff00" exactly.
```

One method I can think of now is to build a map.

```
typedef map<int, string> hex_to_str_map;
hex_to_string_map myMap {
             {0x0,    "0"},
             {0x1,    "1"},
             ...........
             {0xf,    "16"},
        };
```

And then convert the hex number one bit by one bit.

I have tried to use `ostreamstream`, but this will convert hex to decimal

```
template <typename T>
string NumberToString (T that) {
    ostreamstream ss;
    ss << that;
    return ss.str()
}
```

And what I want is to store the converted string to a vector, and use it in another function.

Comment: there is no such thing as a hex number, ints are ints. Your question is "how do I display a number in hex."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892877/cout-print-hex-instead-of-decimal

Comment: @anatolyg thanks man.